# Check if all rows are the same

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a select query that returns multiple rows, and I want to check if all rows are the same. So something like this:

```
anything_other_than(123) in (select id from foo)
```

So, if `select id from foo` returns `111,222,123,333` the statement above is false, and if `select id from foo` returns `123,123,123` it's true. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please, post the complete sql query.

Comment: @TwilightTitus I don't have a complete query, `anything_othert_then` is pseudocode only to explain what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use EXISTS with a where condition:

```
select not exists (select *
                   from the_table
                   where id <> 123);
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution is to use the `= ALL` operator:

```
SELECT 123 = ALL (SELECT id FROM foo);
```

This solution also stop scanning the result as soon as the first non-matching value is found.

Answer (score 2):

Run this:

```
select count(distinct id) = 1 and count(*) > 1 from foo;
```

`count(distinct id)` will return 1 if all the rows are the same 
and `count(*)` will return the total number of rows.
If this returns `true` then you have more than 1 rows and all the rows are the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this -

```
select x, IF(x > 1, "FALSE", "TRUE") from 
(SELECT count(distinct(A.id)) as x FROM foo as A) as B;
```

Do refer this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp

Comment: There is no `if()` in SQL (or Postgres)

Comment: Postgre offers "CASE WHEN condition THEN result". Its just a matter of syntax.